# How Can I install php-imap on openshift

Tags: php, imap, openshift

I have a PHP application running on Openshift and I need receive e-mails from gmail using imap protocol. In my local machine I am able to get emails from gmail using the same code, but when I am running from Openshift I can not get emails. I suppose that the problem is the php-imap which I had to install in my local machine. I am not sure if this module is already installed in Openshift. Should I install php-imap or this module is enable for default on server?

Comment: I believe it is not enabled by default

Comment: Maybe. Do you guess how I can enable that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to integrate email into your app is with Sendgrid from our Oenshift Marketplace here: https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/9628?1665146903&restoreSearch=true#!overview. For reference, here are the extensions available in the php cartridge as of today:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
apc
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3 
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but:

```
[some-domain.rhcloud.com 56956f307628e19496000093]\> php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2015 03:10:33)
...

[some-domain.rhcloud.com 56956f307628e19496000093]\> php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
hash
iconv
imagick
imap 
intl
json
libxml
...

[other-domain.rhcloud.com 5695463d89f5cf0a7e0001b5]\> php -v

PHP 5.4.40 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 06:44:21)
...
[other-domain.rhcloud.com 5695463d89f5cf0a7e0001b5]\> php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
hash
iconv
imagick
intl
json
ldap
libxml
...
```

So, if you need imap module you should use php-5.3